# Mathematica does not responding

Tags: notebooks, kernel

These days, when I opened mathematica 10.4 in Windows 10, I even cannot type three characters, and it stucks. Yes, every time when I type the third number or character, it stops. I found that, even, I opened a blank notebook, there is a high memeroy occupied by mathematica. This is very strange for me. Anyone can give some suggestions ?

Comment: Have you tried the stuff [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TroubleshootingTheWolframSystem.html)?

Comment: Presumably at duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109005/segmentation-fault-on-auto-complete. Also related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111481/mathematica-freezes-on-autocomplete

Comment: Can you check if the answers in the links I posted solve your problem?

Comment: @Lukas  Thanks!　Ｙｅｓ，　ｔｈｉｓ　ｉｓ　ａ　ｄｕｐｌｉｃａｔｅ　ｐｒｏｂｌｅｍ．　Ｎｏｗ　ｉｔ　ｗｏｒｋｓ．　 My CodeAssistHistory10.4m　ｈａｄ　ａ　ｓｉｚｅ　ｏｆ　ｍｏｒｅ　ｔｈａｎ　２００Ｍ！